# Extend walker - navigation, adding data attribute to a tag

Tags: theme-development, menus, navigation, walker, customization

I would a data attribute to the `a` tag in the menu, like have `<a href="#example" data-attribute="attribute">CLICK</a>`

I know that I have to extend the Walker BUT I tried in several times (finding some code on internet) and I never made it work.

Here the code (I've still not tried to insert the `data-attribute` because before I would make the menu works.)
CODE:

```
/* WALKER */
wp_nav_menu( array(
 'container' =>false,
 'menu_class' => 'nav',
 'echo' => true,
 'before' => '',
 'after' => '',
 'link_before' => '',
 'link_after' => '',
 'depth' => 0,
 'walker' => new description_walker())
 );
 class description_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
      function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args)
      {
           global $wp_query;
           $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

           $class_names = $value = '';

           $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

           $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
           $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

           $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';

           $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
           $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
           $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
           $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

           $prepend = '<strong>';
           $append = '</strong>';
           $description  = ! empty( $item->description ) ? '<span>'.esc_attr( $item->description ).'</span>' : '';

           if($depth != 0)
           {
                     $description = $append = $prepend = "";
           }

            $item_output = $args->before;
            $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
            $item_output .= $args->link_before .$prepend.apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ).$append;
            $item_output .= $description.$args->link_after;
            $item_output .= '</a>';
            $item_output .= $args->after;

            $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
            }
}
```

And here the errors:
[image]

Could any help me? 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

This is how I added data attribute to my menu
It simply adds data-title="menu-title" to each link on my main nav, change it to adapt to your need.

You don't actually need to use Nav Walker to add this

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'cfw_add_data_atts_to_nav', 10, 4 );
    function cfw_add_data_atts_to_nav( $atts, $item, $args ) {

    $atts['data-title'] = $item->post_title;
    return $atts;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if things were changed in the most recent version but I had to use `$item->title` instead of `$item->post-title`.

Comment: @Jrod I believe post_title is still valid in 4.3
Is there any links or articles you can provide? If anything has changed I would like to know it as well.

Comment: It seems like `post_title` is empty until you edit the Navigation Label of a menu item.