# Add a data attribute to list item element in menu

Tags: menus, links, customization

Looking to add a data attribute to a **list item** in a menu, I can see that some threads on here can add it to the actual `<a>` link tag, I am looking to add it to the list item itself `<li>`

So this code adds the attribute to the `<a>`tag

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'themeprefix_menu_attribute_add', 10, 3 );
function themeprefix_menu_attribute_add( $atts, $item, $args ) {
  // Set the menu ID
  $menu_link1 = 20;

// Conditionally match the ID and add the attribute and value
if ($item->ID == $menu_link1) {
$atts['data-content'] = 'about';

//Return the new attribute
return $atts;
```

Any ideas how to add the attribute to the `<li>` without using jQuery.

Comment: You can follow this [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/161644/134743). hope it will helped.

Answer (score 0):

try this code in your functions file.

```
function add_class_to_nav_items($nav_items, $args) {
  if ( $args['theme_location'] == 'MY_NAV_THEME_LOCATION' ) { // IMPORTANT: replace MY_NAV_THEME_LOCATION with the location of your menu
    foreach ($nav_items as &$nav_item) {
      $nav_item->classes[] = 'custon-class-name';
    }
  }

  return $nav_items;

}

add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'add_class_to_nav_items', 11 );
```

Comment: Original question asks for adding attributes to `li` tag

Answer (score 0):

there is no filter available to add a custom attribute to the `li` element. only way possible is to use a custom walker.

here is how: (functions.php or custom plugin)

```
class so244415_custom_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        //your code here. the line you want to edit is:
        //$output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $class_names .'>';
    }
}
```

look for the file `class-walker-nav-menu.php` inside wp-includes and copy everything from the certain function `start_el` in there and edit it to your needs.

you would call your menu like so: (in the theme file, where you call your menu)

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'walker' => new so244415_custom_walker( $args ), /*( $args ) is optional...*/ 
));
```

another option would be, to use

```
function so244415_walker_nav_menu_start_el($item_output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    //some regex/str_replace here
    return $item_output;
}
add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'so244415_walker_nav_menu_start_el', 10, 4);
```

but i am not the biggest fan of this solution, since regex and suchlike is not the best way to edit html.